Is it necessary to use setState when removing items from a list in a Dismissible in Flutter?
I'm building a Flutter app where I use a Dismissible widget to allow users to remove items from a list. I've noticed that the UI updates correctly when an item is dismissed, even if I don't call setState.
here is the code:
  @override
  _GroceryListScreenState createState() => _GroceryListScreenState();
}

class _GroceryListScreenState extends State<GroceryListScreen> {
  List<String> groceryItems = ['Apples', 'Bananas', 'Oranges', 'Milk'];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Grocery List'),
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: groceryItems.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return Dismissible(
            key: ValueKey(groceryItems[index]),
            onDismissed: (direction) {
              groceryItems.removeAt(index); // UI updates even without setState
            },
            background: Container(color: Colors.red),
            child: ListTile(
              title: Text(groceryItems[index]),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}


You should, otherwise when the widget is rebuilt, the dismissed items would come back.

It is necessary, groceryItems just removed an item after onDismissed, but ListView haven't noticed that, so you need to call setState to notify ListView, failing to do so will cause a RangeError when you scroll to the end.
